# Insert current date and time using java.util.Date object in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I have a field in MySQL `created_on` with datatype DATETIME. For that field, I have to insert the current date and time. I have taken `java.util.Date` object.

```
Date dateobj = new Date()
String query = "insert into users(created_on) values(?)";
ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateobj.getTime()));
insert_flag=ps.executeUpdate();
```

The query is executing fine but it is inserting only current date with 00:00:00.
I want current date and time (example: 2015-10-28 03:23:50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a date and a time, you need to use [`setTimestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-) instead of [`setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-) and the datatype of your database column must be DATETIME (or TIMESTAMP).

Quoting `setDate` Javadoc:

> The driver converts this to an SQL DATE value when it sends it to the database.

and quoting [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.

Working code:

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```